# Changing opacity of element depending on scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the opacity of elements depending on the position of the scrollbar, but the function somehow will always stop after the first "else if" so nothing will happen with elements "C", "D", "E" eventhough the function still detect the scrollbar position

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
      $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll < 600) {
        document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("B").style.opacity = "0.5";
        document.getElementById("C").style.opacity = "0.5";
        document.getElementById("D").style.opacity = "0.5";
      } 
      else if (600 <= scroll < 1500) {
        document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "0.5";
        document.getElementById("B").style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("C").style.opacity = "0.5";
        document.getElementById("D").style.opacity = "0.5";
      } 
      else if (1500 <= scroll < 2600) {
        document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "0.5";
        document.getElementById("B").style.opacity = "0.5";
        document.getElementById("C").style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("D").style.opacity = "0.5";
      } 
      else if (2600 <= scroll < 3200) {
        document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "0.5";
        document.getElementById("B").style.opacity = "0.5";
        document.getElementById("C").style.opacity = "0.5";
        document.getElementById("D").style.opacity = "1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do x < a < y it must be x < a && a < y...

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll < 600) {
    document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("B").style.opacity = "0.5";
    document.getElementById("C").style.opacity = "0.5";
    document.getElementById("D").style.opacity = "0.5";
  } 
  else if (600 <= scroll && scroll < 1500) {
    document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "0.5";
    document.getElementById("B").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("C").style.opacity = "0.5";
    document.getElementById("D").style.opacity = "0.5";
  } 
  else if (1500 <= scroll && scroll < 2600) {
    document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "0.5";
    document.getElementById("B").style.opacity = "0.5";
    document.getElementById("C").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("D").style.opacity = "0.5";
  } 
  else if (2600 <= scroll && scroll < 3200) {
    document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "0.5";
    document.getElementById("B").style.opacity = "0.5";
    document.getElementById("C").style.opacity = "0.5";
    document.getElementById("D").style.opacity = "1";
```

Comment: omg I'm so stupid xD thank you its work! Sorry I'm kinda new to this stuff